# JavaScript XMLHTTPRequest XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xmlhttprequest

I've written the following code to read an *XML* file and display it, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone show me where I'm going wrong? Try to load and display XML:

```js
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

var tbl = document.createElement("table");
tbl.className = "datatable";
tbl.border = "6";
tbl.width = "500";
tbl.cellPadding = "10";

var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Book");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    var title = x[i].childNodes[0].text;
    var author = x[i].childNodes[1].text;

    //var title = x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    //var author = x[i].getElementsByTagName("author")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.appendChild(title);

    //td.appendChild(author);

    row.appendChild(td);

}
tbody.appendChild(row);
tbl.appendChild(tbody);
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(tbl);
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Books>
<Book>
    <title>A Bend in the river</title>
    <author>V.S. Naipaul</author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <title>Earth</title>
    <author>Emile Zola</author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <title>I am not an Island</title>
    <author>V.S. Naipaul</author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <title>Macbeth</title>
    <author>William Shakespeare</author>
</Book>
<Book>
    <title>Quarantene</title>
    <author>Jim Crass</author>
</Book>
</Books>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hi Russell, welcome to Stack Overflow. The general idea on SO is that you [edit your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626045/use-javascript-dom-methods-to-load-and-display-xml) to improve it, adding in the extra details you've learned. This keeps information from getting spread out across multiple, duplicate questions and also bumps your other question to the top so it's visible. You should remove this one and edit the other one. Consider that your question, and its answers, may help others as well. Good luck! :)

Comment: I've tried to cut down your question to just the relevant items, but it seems like you've been very vague about how your code is not working; expected result vs actual result, or if you get any error messages in your console. If you can be more specific or cut your issue down to a minimal test case, you are more likely to get helpful answers.

Comment: jmort and Paul S, Apologies ... I'm new here so a bit 'blur' about proper procedures for asking questions. Will take note of your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </body>
```

and

```
function load() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "books.xml", false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

    var tbl = document.createElement("table");
    tbl.className = "datatable";
    tbl.border = "6";
    tbl.width = "500";
    tbl.cellPadding = "10";

    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Book");

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var title = x[i].getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
        var author = x[i].getElementsByTagName('author')[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = title;
        row.appendChild(td);

        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = author;
        row.appendChild(td);

        tbody.appendChild(row);

    }
    tbl.appendChild(tbody);
    document.getElementById("content").appendChild(tbl);

}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZorWUs0COxwJYXgMEFt7?p=preview)

Comment: Arun P Johny, I've checked out your demo and got your script running. It does exactly what I wanted. Many thanks!! One question ... could I use a method like appendChild instead of innerHTML?

Answer (score 0):

For prosperity; put together a demo to help debug (skipping *XMLHttpRequest* by using *DOMParser*; if it is successful the `<table>` will be logged in *console*)

Demo fiddle [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t2JQ8/) (and open your console on the page)

As it stands, it looks like you're getting the following error reported

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Which happens on the line

```
td.appendChild(title);
```

This is most likely due to trying to append a *Node* to a *#document* which is not the *ownerDocument* of that *Node*. You will need to use [`document.importNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode) to get around this, or create an equivalent *Node* in the correct *#document* manually.

```
title = document.importNode(title);
td.appendChild(title);
```

This will need to be done for all the other *Nodes*, too.

Comment: Paul S, To tell you the truth I wasn't checking the console (bad form). Have noted your comments. Thank you!